# Logging Error VBA excel Batch command

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, logging, office-2007

I have a batch file contains

```
echo test string >>Log.txt
```

when i click on it it will make a Log.txt file and the "test string" will be in it. But when i run the batch file from VBA excel using WScript.Shell it is not creating the Log.txt file. But the batch code is running. How can I make it working? I am using windows7 and excel 2007

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel/VBA?

Comment: It's more likely that you _don't know where_ the file is than that it's not being created. Run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) while this happens and see where `Log.txt` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest specifying an absolute path to the file.

```
echo test string >>"%USERPROFILE%\Document\Log.txt"
```

The most common frustration I experience when using relative paths is that it's relative to the "working directory" windows uses for the calling process, and if it's launched from Explorer, that can easily be %WINDIR% or some place where you don't want stuff saved.

Comment: It was correct. I have given the absolute path and now its working fine.thanks for the reply